# Error with Java while trying to run iReport-5.5.0

Tags: java, ubuntu, ireport

I ran the command `/iReport-5.5.0/bin$ ./ireport.sh` to run iReport designer but the terminal showed me some errors as following

```
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit..
```

Here is the result of my `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: see http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/825138/ireport-designer-problems-running-jdk-8

Comment: For other visitors: The (deprecated) iReport isn't compatible with Java 8. Consider using Jaspersoft Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using java 8 and IReport is not compatable with that version ... however if you have also old version of java installed (say 1.6.0_26) than you can still run Ireport.

You can edit  ireport.conf file (e.g. iReport-5.5.0\etc\ireport.conf)
and add

`jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26"`

Note that you should have java6 jdk also installed on your system for the above to work.